# How to reorder methods in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to change the order of methods in PyCharm? I would expect a dialog similar to that for changing the order of parameters in a function call, but I can't find it.

The only way I am aware of explicitely copy/pasting the code.

If it is possible then how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try these:

- [Move Class/Function Dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-class-function-dialog.html)
- [Move statements](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/adding-deleting-and-moving-code-elements.html) using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Down</kbd>

Comment: Move class/function only works for moving classes functions between files not for reordering. The keyboard commands are exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Using `Ctrl+Shift+Minus` and `Ctrl+Shift+Plus` to collapse all the functions in a file helps a lot.